# Powershell does not put system variable in path

Tags: powershell

Putting the following in a Powershell console, it outputs the variable value:

```
[Environment]::UserName
```

Putting this:

```
PS C:\> Test-Path C:\Users\${[Environment]::UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
False
```

Odd, so I went ahead and outputted to the console itself:

```
PS C:\> Write-Host C:\Users\${[Environment]::UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
```

It returns blank. Why? Putting the variable directly to console does output its value while passing it like that it doesnt...

Comment: `${[Environment]::UserName}` and `$([Environment]::UserName)` are different things.

Comment: why not use the `env` ps-drive ? `$env:username` ?

Comment: Are you sure the path being output is correct; i.e. that the username's appended?  When I run it I see `c:\Users\\AppData\...`; i.e. no username.

Comment: $env:username works. Now I have to figure out (just in case) to uppercase it. Shouldnt be that difficult I think.

Comment: Write-Host C:\Users\${env:username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$env:LOCALAPPDATA` since you don't have to hard code `c:\`. You should also use the [Join-Path cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849799(v=WPS.620).aspx) if you want to join a path:

```
$path = Join-Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA 'Microsoft\Outlook'
```

Comment: This is a better solution than my answer (leaving my answer in place since it shows a way of achieving what the OP requested in a similar way) for this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I also use the format string to put variables into a string all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the path being output is correct; i.e. that the username's appended? When I run it I see `c:\Users\\AppData\...;` i.e. no username.

Working code:

```
$fn = ("C:\Users\{0}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" -f $env:Username)
Write-Host $fn
Test-Path $fn
```